# POST http://localhost:3000/auth/signin 404 (Not Found), 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST'

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios, http-status-code-404

I have am trying to connect my frontend to my backend using axios to make API calls. My client is running on port 3000 and server on port 8800. When I try to fetch videos it is working fine, means the proxy server is setup correctly. However during signin authentication the code gives the following error - [error that im getting on pressing the signin button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9gMx.png)

The code are as follows -
Here I've tried to set a proxy server in my client package.json.

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.12",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.8",
    "timeago.js": "^4.0.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8800/api/"
}
```

This is the signin.jsx handleLogin function triggered on clicking the signin button

```
const handleLogin = async (e)=> {
    e.preventDefault();
    try{
      const res = await axios.post("/auth/signin", {username, password});
      console.log(res.data);
    }catch(err){
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

And I've been tring to post to the exact same route - [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBPxI.png)
Ive tried disabling and enabling cors too.
How do i solve this and get port 3000 connected 8800 and signin working ?

Comment: Are you sure on the backend you are expecting a path of `/api`? Provide the route handlers for `/auth/signin`. Since it's not clarified, if you are using express.js then I expect you to have something like `app.use('/api', userRouter)` make sure it is "`/api`" and not an empty "`/`" path

Comment: Oh and one more thing can you test if you run the full URL in your `signin.jsx` would it work? Like `axios.post('http://localhost:8800/api/auth/signin',...` if it does, then you need to stop React and re-start it so that *proxy* changes can catch up!